# HTTP Angular 2?

Tags: typescript, angular, http-headers

Does anyone know how to add or create a custom HTTP header using Angular 2?
how to inject the http depency and how to use the header as we used in jquery

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'foo/bar',
    headers: { 'x-my-custom-header': 'some value' }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('x-my-custom-header', 'some value');

http.get('foo/bar', { headers: headers });
```

Of course you can use headers with the rest of the http methods.

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps to use the HTTP support of Angular2:

- Specify the HTTP module in the SystemJS configuration:

  ```
  System.config({
    (...)
    map: {
      app: "./src",
     '@angular': 'https://npmcdn.com/@angular',
     'rxjs': 'https://npmcdn.com/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6'
   },
   packages: {
     app: {
       main: './main.ts',
       defaultExtension: 'js'
     },
     '@angular/core': {
       main: 'core.umd.js',
       defaultExtension: 'js'
     },
     (...)
     '@angular/http': {
       main: 'http.umd.js',
       defaultExtension: 'js'
     },
     rxjs: {
       defaultExtension: 'js'
     }
    }
  });
  ```
- Set the HTTP_PROVIDERS providers when bootstrapping your application:

  ```
  bootstrap(AppComponent, [ HTTP_PROVIDERS ]);
  ```
- Inject an instance of the `Http` class where you want to execute an HTTP request:

  ```
  import {Http} from '@angular/http';

  @Component({
    (...)
  })
  // It can also be @Injectable() in the case of a service
  export class SomeComponent {
    constructor(private http:Http) {
    }
  }
  ```
- Use the Http instance to execute the request:

  ```
  import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';

  @Component({
    (...)
  })
  // It can also be @Injectable() in the case of a service
  export class SomeComponent {
    (...)

    executeRequest() {
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('x-my-custom-header', 'some value');

      this.http.get('foo/bar', { headers });
    }
  ```
- Subscribe on the request response to get the response

  ```
    executeRequest() {
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('x-my-custom-header', 'some value');

      this.http.get('foo/bar', { headers }).map(res => res.json())
         .subscribe((data) => {
           this.data = data;
         });
    }
  ```

  Don't forget this step since observables are lazy. So without subscribing on them, requests won't be executed

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you wrap the Http service in your own service that defines your REST endpoints like this:

```
    import { Injectable, } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

import { Headers, Http, Response, RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';


@Injectable()
export class RestService {
    constructor(private http: Http) {}
    get<T>(url: string): Observable<T> {
        var options = {} as RequestOptionsArgs;
        options.headers = this.prepareRequestHeaders();
        return this.http.get(url, options)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
    post<T>(url: string, data: any): Observable<T> {
        var options = {} as RequestOptionsArgs;
        options.headers = this.prepareRequestHeaders();
        return this.http.post(url, data, options)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
    put<T>(url: string, data: any): Observable<T> {
        var options = {} as RequestOptionsArgs;
        options.headers = this.prepareRequestHeaders();
        return this.http.put(url, data, options)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
    patch<T>(url: string, data: any): Observable<T> {
        var options = {} as RequestOptionsArgs;
        options.headers = this.prepareRequestHeaders();
        return this.http.patch(url, data, options)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
    delete<T>(url: string): Observable<T> {
        var options = {} as RequestOptionsArgs;
        options.headers = this.prepareRequestHeaders();
        return this.http.delete(url, options)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private extractData<T>(response: Response) {
        var resp: T;
        try {
            resp = response.json() as T;
        } catch (error) {
        }
        return resp;
    }

    private prepareRequestHeaders() {
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('x-my-custom-header', 'some value');
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
       // etc
        return headers;
    }


    private handleResponse<T>(response: any): T[] {
        var resp: T[];
        try {
            resp = response.json().data as T[];
        } catch (error) {
        }
        return resp;
    }
    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

**or if you prefer promise:**

```
import { Injectable, } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { Headers, Http, Response, RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';


@Injectable()
export class RestService {
    constructor(private http: Http) {}
    get<T>(url: string): Promise<T> {
        var options = {} as RequestOptionsArgs;
        options.headers = this.prepareRequestHeaders();
        return this.http.get(url, options)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError).toPromise();
    }
    post<T>(url: string, data: any):Promise<T> {
        var options = {} as RequestOptionsArgs;
        options.headers = this.prepareRequestHeaders();
        return this.http.post(url, data, options)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError).toPromise();
    }
    put<T>(url: string, data: any):Promise<T> {
        var options = {} as RequestOptionsArgs;
        options.headers = this.prepareRequestHeaders();
        return this.http.put(url, data, options)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError).toPromise();
    }
    patch<T>(url: string, data: any):Promise<T> {
        var options = {} as RequestOptionsArgs;
        options.headers = this.prepareRequestHeaders();
        return this.http.patch(url, data, options)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError).toPromise();
    }
    delete<T>(url: string):Promise<T> {
        var options = {} as RequestOptionsArgs;
        options.headers = this.prepareRequestHeaders();
        return this.http.delete(url, options)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError).toPromise();
    }

    private extractData<T>(response: Response) {
        var resp: T;
        try {
            resp = response.json() as T;
        } catch (error) {
        }
        return resp;
    }

    private prepareRequestHeaders() {
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('x-my-custom-header', 'some value');
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
       // etc
        return headers;
    }


    private handleResponse<T>(response: any): T[] {
        var resp: T[];
        try {
            resp = response.json().data as T[];
        } catch (error) {
        }
        return resp;
    }
    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

Comment: This one is for when I user observable design patterns